# output window in notepad++

Tags: php, compiler-construction, notepad++

How do I get to see the output of a php compiler in notepad++ ? I see that there is a console output window in notepad++ but nothing gets displayed there.

Comment: Make sure display_errors is "On". Either pass "-d display_error=On" to php.exe, or modify the setting in php.ini.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

To test for errors in a PHP file, open up nppexec dialog by pressing F6 and type in

```
"<full path to php.exe>" "-ln" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

save the new script and name it as you feel comfortable. You can assign a shortcut key to execute this script in

```
settings->Shortcut mapper->Plugin commands
```

once there, scroll down and search for the script you saved.

For even more convenience, press `Shidt+F6` to bring up nppexec's line highlights. Put in `%ABSFILE% on line %LINE%` and tick the checkbox to enable this filter. You will be able to click the error string to go straight to the line with the problem.

Comment: Helpfully so need only in cmd type script name :)

Answer (score 0):

In the console dialog, type `cmd` to get the windows command prompt. Then, to execute a php file, type `php -f /path/to/file.php`

You can also run arbitrary php snippets using the syntax `php -r 'echo phpversion();'`

You may need to first navigate to the folder that contains the php executable.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can make a specified command run in the console dialog every time by pressing a key? For example, I press F5 and the command is executed. Is this possible ?